# How to Display images from SD Card to ListView with the New Folder Picker API?

Tags: android, listview, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I am trying to select a folder from SD Card and display the list of images inside this folder.

It was working fine until Android 5.0, 
so I started updating it with the New SD Card Access API to pick the folder.

```
public void FolderSelectionAlertDialog_Lollipop() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 556);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {          
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Get Uri from Storage Access Framework.
        Uri_Lollipop = resultData.getData();        

        // Persist access permissions.
        this.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(Uri_Lollipop,
             Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);           

    }
}
```

For some reasons, there is no image showing in the ListView.

Here is the code:

```
public void ListView_Load_Lollipop() {
    DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, Uri_Lollipop);
    Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
    for(DocumentFile file : documentFile.listFiles()) {
        String FileName = file.getName();
        if(FileName.toLowerCase(defaultLocale).endsWith(".jpg") || 
           FileName.toLowerCase(defaultLocale).endsWith(".png") || 
           FileName.toLowerCase(defaultLocale).endsWith(".jpeg")) {

            mListViewObject = new ListViewObject();
            mListViewObject.setName(FileName);
            Uri uri = file.getUri();
            String imagePath = uri.getPath();
            mListViewObject.setImageUrl("file:///" + imagePath); 
            ListViewObject_List.add(mListViewObject); 
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {       
  ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, parent, false);
      viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListViewImage); 
      convertView.setTag(viewHolder);            
  } 
 else 
  {
     viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
  }

  Picasso.with(mContext)
  .load(getItem(position).getImageUrl())
  .fit()      
  .centerCrop()
  .into(viewHolder.imageView);
}
class ViewHolder {
RelativeLayout layout;
ImageView imageView;
}
```

Can someone please guide me on this?

Thanks a lot

**Update: 4-28-16**

I forgot to add this

```
listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, ListViewObject_List);
listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
```

to

```
public void ListView_Load_Lollipop() {
    DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, Uri_Lollipop);
    Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
    for(DocumentFile file : documentFile.listFiles()) {
        String FileName = file.getName();
        if(FileName.toLowerCase(defaultLocale).endsWith(".jpg") || 
           FileName.toLowerCase(defaultLocale).endsWith(".png") || 
           FileName.toLowerCase(defaultLocale).endsWith(".jpeg")) {

            mListViewObject = new ListViewObject();
            mListViewObject.setName(FileName);
            Uri uri = file.getUri();
            String imagePath = uri.getPath();
            mListViewObject.setImageUrl("file:///" + imagePath); 
            ListViewObject_List.add(mListViewObject); 
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to @CommonsWare's answer: I was able to resolve my problem by passing the image **Uri** instead of the **image path** directly to the object class.

I hope it helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no requirement that a `Uri` end in a file extension. Use `getType()` on your `DocumentFile` and see if the MIME type is of type image.
2. `"file:///" + imagePath` is utterly meaningless. A `Uri` is not a file. Pass the `Uri` itself into whatever `setImageUrl()` is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I've tried to send uri directly to the object class, but the images still don't show up on the ListView.  The image will show up on the ImageView with my original code.  There is an issue with the ListView somehow.

Comment: @Dante: Make sure the unmodified `Uri` is what you are passing to Picasso.

Comment: OMG, it works!  I forgot to add this      listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, ListViewObject_List);
     listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);  That's why the adapter wasn't working.  After I passed the uri directly to the Object class, it works.  Thank  you so much

Answer (score 1):

Please check the error in getView() code by adding the code:-

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(mActivity);
    builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
            Log.e("", "" + uri.getPath());
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    Picasso pic = builder.build();
    pic.load(file).into(holder.mDataIV);
```

By this you will be able to identify the error. It will help you to solve the problem. As per my understanding Picasso not able to load image if it is not being able to find the image. Here is the helper class which will return you the actual path of the image:-

FilePathHelper.java[Referral Link](https://gist.github.com/asifmujteba/d89ba9074bc941de1eaa#file-asfurihelper)

```
public class FilePathHelper {
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```

and you just have to edit your method ListView_Load_Lollipop()

```
public void ListView_Load_Lollipop() {
    DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, Uri_Lollipop);
    Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
    for(DocumentFile file : documentFile.listFiles()) {
        String FileName = file.getName();
        if(FileName.toLowerCase(defaultLocale).endsWith(".jpg") ||
                FileName.toLowerCase(defaultLocale).endsWith(".png") ||
                FileName.toLowerCase(defaultLocale).endsWith(".jpeg")) {

            Uri uri = file.getUri();
            Uri docUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(uri,
                    DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(uri));
            String path = FilePathHelper.getPath(this, docUri);
            mListData.add(path+ File.separator+FileName);
        }
    }
    NewImageAdapter newImageAdapter = new NewImageAdapter(this,this,mListData);
    mUserListRV.setAdapter(newImageAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer anyway.  At least, the onImageLoadFailed is still useful, thanks a lot